# Locale not working when called from a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, actionmailer

I have a Rails app (2.3.8) where I send emails using ActionMailer from my Controllers, with no problems.

However, I´ve created a rake task to be called from a Cronjob (in Heroku). When those emails are sent, no locale transformations in my dates are made.

I´ve googled to find any kind of solution, but couldn´t.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks.

Here is the code:

cron.rake:

```
desc 'This task is called by the Heroku cron add-on'  
task :cron => :environment do  
puts 'Sending diary...'  
hollydays = [6,0] #weekend    
unless hollydays.member?(Time.zone.now.wday) #if is NOT a weekend   
 User.all.each do |user|  
   user.deliver_task_diary
 end  
end  
puts 'done.'  
end
```

user model method:

```
def deliver_task_diary
  TaskMailer.deliver_task_diary(self)
end
```

the method in TaskMailer model:

```
def task_diary(user)
  next_five_tasks = user.next_five_tasks
  last_five_tasks = user.last_five_tasks

  recipients "#{user.name} <#{user.email}>"
  from       "My site <no_reply@mysite.com>"
  subject    "Your daily tasks."
  sent_on    Time.zone.now
  body       :user => user, :next_five_tasks => next_five_tasks, :last_five_tasks => last_five_tasks
```

end

part of my email template that doesn´t locale:

```
<%=l task.estimated_delivery_date, :format => :short %>
```

Comment: How are you setting the locale in your controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

I don´t know if it´s the best way, but I´ve just declared the locale at the very beging of the email html template:

```
<% I18n.locale = "pt-BR" %>
```